# Vagrant package error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am trying to package new vagrant base box. And I get this error while doing so.

```
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.1/plugins/commands/package/command.rb:59:in `package_base': C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.1/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:358: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant1.5.1/plugins/commands/package/command.rb:42:in `execute'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.1/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:42:in `execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:248:in `cli'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.1/bin/vagrant:158:in `<main>'
```

The content of "machine.rb" is below.

```
require "thread"

require "log4r"

module Vagrant
  # This represents a machine that Vagrant manages. This provides a singular
  # API for querying the state and making state changes to the machine, which
  # is backed by any sort of provider (VirtualBox, VMWare, etc.).
  class Machine
    # The box that is backing this machine.
    #
    # @return [Box]
    attr_accessor :box

    # Configuration for the machine.
    #
    # @return [Object]
    attr_accessor :config

    # Directory where machine-specific data can be stored.
    #
    # @return [Pathname]
    attr_reader :data_dir

    # The environment that this machine is a part of.
    #
    # @return [Environment]
    attr_reader :env

    # ID of the machine. This ID comes from the provider and is not
    # guaranteed to be of any particular format except that it is
    # a string.
    #
    # @return [String]
    attr_reader :id

    # Name of the machine. This is assigned by the Vagrantfile.
    #
    # @return [Symbol]
    attr_reader :name

    # The provider backing this machine.
    #
    # @return [Object]
    attr_reader :provider

    # The provider-specific configuration for this machine.
    #
    # @return [Object]
    attr_accessor :provider_config

    # The name of the provider.
    #
    # @return [Symbol]
    attr_reader :provider_name

    # The options given to the provider when registering the plugin.
    #
    # @return [Hash]
    attr_reader :provider_options

    # The UI for outputting in the scope of this machine.
    #
    # @return [UI]
    attr_reader :ui

    # The Vagrantfile that this machine is attached to.
    #
    # @return [Vagrantfile]
    attr_reader :vagrantfile

    # Initialize a new machine.
    #
    # @param [String] name Name of the virtual machine.
    # @param [Class] provider The provider backing this machine. This is
    #   currently expected to be a V1 `provider` plugin.
    # @param [Object] provider_config The provider-specific configuration for
    #   this machine.
    # @param [Hash] provider_options The provider-specific options from the
    #   plugin definition.
    # @param [Object] config The configuration for this machine.
    # @param [Pathname] data_dir The directory where machine-specific data
    #   can be stored. This directory is ensured to exist.
    # @param [Box] box The box that is backing this virtual machine.
    # @param [Environment] env The environment that this machine is a
    #   part of.
    def initialize(name, provider_name, provider_cls, provider_config, provider_options, config, data_dir, box, env, vagrantfile, base=false)
      @logger = Log4r::Logger.new("vagrant::machine")
      @logger.info("Initializing machine: #{name}")
      @logger.info("  - Provider: #{provider_cls}")
      @logger.info("  - Box: #{box}")
      @logger.info("  - Data dir: #{data_dir}")

      @box             = box
      @config          = config
      @data_dir        = data_dir
      @env             = env
      @vagrantfile     = vagrantfile
      @guest           = Guest.new(
        self,
        Vagrant.plugin("2").manager.guests,
        Vagrant.plugin("2").manager.guest_capabilities)
      @name            = name
      @provider_config = provider_config
      @provider_name   = provider_name
      @provider_options = provider_options
      @ui              = Vagrant::UI::Prefixed.new(@env.ui, @name)
      @ui_mutex        = Mutex.new

      # Read the ID, which is usually in local storage
      @id = nil

      # XXX: This is temporary. This will be removed very soon.
      if base
        @id = name
      else
        # Read the id file from the data directory if it exists as the
        # ID for the pre-existing physical representation of this machine.
        id_file = @data_dir.join("id")
        @id = id_file.read.chomp if id_file.file?
      end

      # Initializes the provider last so that it has access to all the
      # state we setup on this machine.
      @provider = provider_cls.new(self)
      @provider._initialize(@provider_name, self)
    end

    # This calls an action on the provider. The provider may or may not
    # actually implement the action.
    #
    # @param [Symbol] name Name of the action to run.
    # @param [Hash] extra_env This data will be passed into the action runner
    #   as extra data set on the environment hash for the middleware
    #   runner.
    def action(name, extra_env=nil)
      @logger.info("Calling action: #{name} on provider #{@provider}")

      # Get the callable from the provider.
      callable = @provider.action(name)

      # If this action doesn't exist on the provider, then an exception
      # must be raised.
      if callable.nil?
        raise Errors::UnimplementedProviderAction,
          :action => name,
          :provider => @provider.to_s
      end

      # Run the action with the action runner on the environment
      env = {
        :action_name    => "machine_action_#{name}".to_sym,
        :machine        => self,
        :machine_action => name,
        :ui             => @ui
      }.merge(extra_env || {})
      @env.action_runner.run(callable, env)
    end

    # Returns a communication object for executing commands on the remote
    # machine. Note that the _exact_ semantics of this are up to the
    # communication provider itself. Despite this, the semantics are expected
    # to be consistent across operating systems. For example, all linux-based
    # systems should have similar communication (usually a shell). All
    # Windows systems should have similar communication as well. Therefore,
    # prior to communicating with the machine, users of this method are
    # expected to check the guest OS to determine their behavior.
    #
    # This method will _always_ return some valid communication object.
    # The `ready?` API can be used on the object to check if communication
    # is actually ready.
    #
    # @return [Object]
    def communicate
      if !@communicator
        # For now, we always return SSH. In the future, we'll abstract
        # this and allow plugins to define new methods of communication.
        klass = Vagrant.plugin("2").manager.communicators[:ssh]
        @communicator = klass.new(self)
      end

      @communicator
    end

    # Returns a guest implementation for this machine. The guest implementation
    # knows how to do guest-OS specific tasks, such as configuring networks,
    # mounting folders, etc.
    #
    # @return [Guest]
    def guest
      raise Errors::MachineGuestNotReady if !communicate.ready?
      @guest.detect! if !@guest.ready?
      @guest
    end

    # This sets the unique ID associated with this machine. This will
    # persist this ID so that in the future Vagrant will be able to find
    # this machine again. The unique ID must be absolutely unique to the
    # virtual machine, and can be used by providers for finding the
    # actual machine associated with this instance.
    #
    # **WARNING:** Only providers should ever use this method.
    #
    # @param [String] value The ID.
    def id=(value)
      @logger.info("New machine ID: #{value.inspect}")

      # The file that will store the id if we have one. This allows the
      # ID to persist across Vagrant runs.
      id_file = @data_dir.join("id")

      if value
        # Write the "id" file with the id given.
        id_file.open("w+") do |f|
          f.write(value)
        end
      else
        # Delete the file, since the machine is now destroyed
        id_file.delete if id_file.file?

        # Delete the entire data directory contents since all state
        # associated with the VM is now gone.
        @data_dir.children.each do |child|
          begin
            child.rmtree
          rescue Errno::EACCES
            @logger.info("EACCESS deleting file: #{child}")
          end
        end
      end

      # Store the ID locally
      @id = value.nil? ? nil : value.to_s

      # Notify the provider that the ID changed in case it needs to do
      # any accounting from it.
      @provider.machine_id_changed
    end

    # This returns a clean inspect value so that printing the value via
    # a pretty print (`p`) results in a readable value.
    #
    # @return [String]
    def inspect
      "#<#{self.class}: #{@name} (#{@provider.class})>"
    end

    # This returns the SSH info for accessing this machine. This SSH info
    # is queried from the underlying provider. This method returns `nil` if
    # the machine is not ready for SSH communication.
    #
    # The structure of the resulting hash is guaranteed to contain the
    # following structure, although it may return other keys as well
    # not documented here:
    #
    #     {
    #       :host => "1.2.3.4",
    #       :port => "22",
    #       :username => "mitchellh",
    #       :private_key_path => "/path/to/my/key"
    #     }
    #
    # Note that Vagrant makes no guarantee that this info works or is
    # correct. This is simply the data that the provider gives us or that
    # is configured via a Vagrantfile. It is still possible after this
    # point when attempting to connect via SSH to get authentication
    # errors.
    #
    # @return [Hash] SSH information.
    def ssh_info
      # First, ask the provider for their information. If the provider
      # returns nil, then the machine is simply not ready for SSH, and
      # we return nil as well.
      info = @provider.ssh_info
      return nil if info.nil?

      # Delete out the nil entries.
      info.dup.each do |key, value|
        info.delete(key) if value.nil?
      end

      # We set the defaults
      info[:host] ||= @config.ssh.default.host
      info[:port] ||= @config.ssh.default.port
      info[:private_key_path] ||= @config.ssh.default.private_key_path
      info[:username] ||= @config.ssh.default.username

      # We set overrides if they are set. These take precedence over
      # provider-returned data.
      info[:host] = @config.ssh.host if @config.ssh.host
      info[:port] = @config.ssh.port if @config.ssh.port
      info[:username] = @config.ssh.username if @config.ssh.username
      info[:password] = @config.ssh.password if @config.ssh.password

      # We also set some fields that are purely controlled by Varant
      info[:forward_agent] = @config.ssh.forward_agent
      info[:forward_x11]   = @config.ssh.forward_x11

      # Add in provided proxy command config
      info[:proxy_command] = @config.ssh.proxy_command if @config.ssh.proxy_command

      # Set the private key path. If a specific private key is given in
      # the Vagrantfile we set that. Otherwise, we use the default (insecure)
      # private key, but only if the provider didn't give us one.
      if !info[:private_key_path] && !info[:password]
        if @config.ssh.private_key_path
          info[:private_key_path] = @config.ssh.private_key_path
        else
          info[:private_key_path] = @env.default_private_key_path
        end
      end

      # If we have a private key in our data dir, then use that
      if !@data_dir.nil?
      data_private_key = @data_dir.join("private_key")
      if data_private_key.file?
      info[:private_key_path] = [data_private_key.to_s]
      end

      # Setup the keys
      info[:private_key_path] ||= []
      if !info[:private_key_path].is_a?(Array)
        info[:private_key_path] = [info[:private_key_path]]
      end

      # Expand the private key path relative to the root path
      info[:private_key_path].map! do |path|
        File.expand_path(path, @env.root_path)
      end

      # Return the final compiled SSH info data
      info
    end

    # Returns the state of this machine. The state is queried from the
    # backing provider, so it can be any arbitrary symbol.
    #
    # @return [MachineState]
    def state
      result = @provider.state
      raise Errors::MachineStateInvalid if !result.is_a?(MachineState)
      result
    end

    # Temporarily changes the machine UI. This is useful if you want
    # to execute an {#action} with a different UI.
    def with_ui(ui)
      @ui_mutex.synchronize do
        begin
          old_ui = @ui
          @ui    = ui
          yield
        ensure
          @ui = old_ui
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In method `ssh_info` you are missing an `end` statement after line 318:

Your code:

```
  # If we have a private key in our data dir, then use that
  if !@data_dir.nil?
  data_private_key = @data_dir.join("private_key")
  if data_private_key.file?
  info[:private_key_path] = [data_private_key.to_s]
  end
```

What it should be:

```
  # If we have a private key in our data dir, then use that
  if !@data_dir.nil?
    data_private_key = @data_dir.join("private_key")
    if data_private_key.file?
      info[:private_key_path] = [data_private_key.to_s]
    end
  end    # <-- this is missing
```

This type of error always gets reported on the last line of the file because it's looking to close the block and reaches the end of the file without getting enough `end` statements.

Comment: No problem; please accept the answer by clicking on the tick to the left of it.